# ng-bind-html does not update the record angularjs 1.6

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Unable to reload data in html (view)

Its loading fine only in first time (page load) , on button click it doesn't reflect changes though controller has the correct record .

#### View -

```
<div class="well" ng-app="myQuizApp"> <fieldset ng-repeat="Question in ::qstns">
 </fieldset> </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="Load_Quizes('2')">Review</button>
```

#### Anguar js library refereed here 1.6

```
myApp.controller("myQuizs", function ($scope, angularService, $window, $sce,$interval) {

var action = 'qiz1';
Load_Quizes(1); // Triggering page load (working fine)

// While calling the function in button click , it gets triggered and contains correct data but ng-repeat does not updates (holds old records) .

    function Load_Quizes(qtnserial) {
        var getQuzData = angularService.LoadQuizes(action, qtnserial);
        getQuzData.then(function (response) {
            try {
                //LOAD QUESTION CHOICE                
                if (response.data != null) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.Quiz = response.data;
                    if ($scope.Quiz.Quiz_id > 0) {
                        $scope.qst_toask = $scope.Quiz.Quiz_Name.split('"').join('');
                        $scope.qstns = $scope.Quiz.QuizQuestiones;
                    } else {
                        $window.alert("Online mock test / Quiz does not exists.");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $window.alert("Online mock test / Quiz does not exists.");
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                $window.alert('Quiz response error.');
            }

        }, function () {
            alert('Error in getting records.');
        });
    }
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: ng-click="Load_Quizes('2')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define Load_Quizes function on `$scope`. Angular binds the view to the controller using `$scope`. Also remove `::` from `ng-repeat="Question in ::qstns"` since it is used for one way binding. Any changes in qstns happening in controller will not be reflected in the view if you use one way binding.

```
$scope.Load_Quizes(1);

$scope.Load_Quizes(qtnserial) {
    var getQuzData = angularService.LoadQuizes(action, qtnserial);
    getQuzData.then(function (response) {
        try {
            //LOAD QUESTION CHOICE                
            if (response.data != null) {
                debugger;
                $scope.Quiz = response.data;
                if ($scope.Quiz.Quiz_id > 0) {
                    $scope.qst_toask = $scope.Quiz.Quiz_Name.split('"').join('');
                    $scope.qstns = $scope.Quiz.QuizQuestiones;
                } else {
                    $window.alert("Online mock test / Quiz does not exists.");
                }
            }
            else {
                $window.alert("Online mock test / Quiz does not exists.");
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            $window.alert('Quiz response error.');
        }

    }, function () {
        alert('Error in getting records.');
    });
}
```

Comment: $scope.Load_Quizes(1);
Loading perfectly , problem is while clicking the button - > Load_Quizes  also gets called and has the correct JSON data .. but data not gets reflect in 
 ng-repeat

Comment: Try removing :: from qstns since it is used for one way binding

Comment: Thank you @Vivz

From last three days I am trying.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please upvote the answer if it helped you and happy holidays :)